# CodeIgniter - Passing two variables from view to controller function

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to pass two variables from the view to the controller. One is the $id of a row that I want to delete from the database. This is working. The other is the $filename of an image that I want to remove from the uploads folder at the same time. I get a server error and I am not sure how else to go about doing this. I am sure it is something simple. Any ideas? Thanks.

//view

```
<input type="button" onClick="location.href = '<?php echo site_url("myfunction/delete/{$row['id']}/{$row['file_name']}"); ?>'" value="Delete" />
```

//controller

```
public function delete($id, $file_name) {

    $table_name = $this->table_name;
    delete_files('../uploads/$file_name');

    $this->load->model('delete', 'delete_model');
    $this->delete_model->delete_row($id, $table_name);

    redirect(site_url('site'));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
delete_files('../uploads/$file_name');
```

to

```
delete_files("../uploads/$file_name");
```

or

```
delete_files('../uploads/'.$file_name);
```

Using single quotes does not expand variables to their values:

```
$x = "onetwo";
$y1 = '$x';
$y2 = "$x";
$y3 = $x;

echo $y1; // $x
echo $y2; // onetwo
echo $y3; // onetwo
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That got rid of the server error! However my file is still not being deleted. It is in an "uploads" folder in the root along with the "application" and "system" folders. Am I calling to it wrong with ../ ? Thanks.

Comment: Can't say for sure, but I think it is relative to your model/controller, so if your code is in `application/models/model.php` then it should be `../../../uploads/...`

Comment: The code is in application/controllers/mycontroller.php. I have tried a bunch of pathing variations ../../   ../../../  but still not deleting. Regardless, thanks for your help.

Comment: try `echo`'ing your file paths that CodeIgniter's upload class gives you when upload is complete, it could be also `realpath()` type paths. Feel free to ask for help anytime